# Passing Array as argument to SOAPMessage Java

Tags: java, xml, web-services, soap

I am trying to create a webService client for a WS that gets an int[] as argument and return it after doing some operations.

The problem is that while i am creating the SOAPMessage request i dont know how to add an array to the SOAPMessage.

The only peace of code i found is from the book Java and SOAP from OREILY that uses this two imports

import org.apache.soap.*; 
import org.apache.soap.rpc.*;

to create the SOAPMessage but they are not included in the standard version of java 6.

When i am trying to test the WebService i get no information about the structure of the SoapMessage when passing an Array

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <S:Header/>
    <S:Body>
        <ns2:dataTransfer xmlns:ns2="http://bigDataTransferPKG/"/>
    </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

And this is the code as it is automatically created from netbeans7.2

```
@WebService(serviceName = "bigDataTransferService")
@Stateless()
public class bigDataTransferService {

    /**
     * Web service operation
     */
    @WebMethod(operationName = "dataTransfer")
    public int[] dataTransfer(@WebParam(name = "data") int[] data) {
        //TODO write your implementation code here:
        return data;
   }
}
```

instead when i am testing a web service that gets 2 int as parameter i get this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <S:Header/>
    <S:Body>
        <ns2:sum xmlns:ns2="http://additionerPKG/">
            <number1>23</number1>
            <number2>32</number2>
        </ns2:sum>
    </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

So i dont know neither how the Soap Request should be let alone how to create it :)

I am a little lost,i hope i explained it in a good level to understand me :)

Thank you in advance

Comment: Does the WSDL define that the field in question accepts an array? Can you post the WSDL as well?

Comment: In what field of the WSDL should i see this ? The WebService is created by net beans 7.2 automatically .I have made an automatic client and link the Service and the client and it worked. But now i want to write the client down myself and call the WebService with the SoapRequest that i will have create on my own

Comment: In this request, there is no such field. If you want to pass an array, then there should be an array , say numbers, and not number1 or number2.

Comment: The sum field is from another web service just to show that when i am  constructing a Soap for a web service that gets 2 int as parameter its pretty simple because i know from the Test webService what Soap To construct. The first Code example is from the WebService that gets an int[] as input.But the test WebService does not give me any info about how to construct the SOAP

Comment: Looks like we have to see more code to answer.

Comment: I have reEdited my post and i added the code from the Web Service but as i told you is a very simple WS that only gets An array of int.I just want to create a SoapRequest for this WS

Comment: @stratisbellos - is there a reason why you want to abandon the auto-generated client and construct the SOAP request yourself? It just seems like you're creating too much work for yourself.

Comment: @Catchwa its because i want to convert the SoapMessage to Byte[] Encrypt it and send it inside another SoapMessage so only the Server that will Invoke the Web Service will know what are the Contents of the SoapMessage all the other servers in the middle will just forward an encrypted SoapMessage . Its a little bit complex system in order to avoid liking info to intermediary servers

Comment: @stratisbellos - isn't that what HTTPS is for? :)

Comment: @Catchwa no Https its to malicious personσ to intervene to the communication.I dont want the server that receives the message to know what the message contains except the one in the end that will invoke the WebService.So thats the reason that Https dont work

Comment: To prevent malicious persons***